# Green Recorder crashes and freeze on Ubuntu 17.10 (Dell XPS 12 DUO) - some advices?

Tags: 17.10, freeze

Greeen Recorder after clicking record freeze system

Comment: Buggy software? I have heard the same complaint from others too.

Comment: Does `/var/log/syslog` reveal any message on that time the freeze happened?

Comment: Are you logging in with Xorg or Wayland session? (Wayland is the default.)

Comment: On x.org working, Weyland no